# Optional password confirmation in has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to turn off password confirmation in **bcrypt-ruby (has_secure_password)** gem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change *password* validation to work only in *create* action.

```
validates :password, presence: true,
                     length: { minimum: 6 },
                     on: :create
```

Comment: Note that if you do this, and you have a mechanism to allow your users to change their passwords (e.g. forgotten password), they will be able to set new passwords that are too short. The reason is that the length validation will not kick off on password update.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want password confirmation at all you can simply not set the :password_confirmation field and the authentication won't be triggered.

Find out more here: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5131

**Rails 4 edit**: Since the introduction of strong params this isn't relevant any more. Simply remove the confirmation field from the sign up form and the parameter isn't passed.

Answer (score 0):

`has_secure_password` is actually part of ActiveModel, and is not itself a gem. The bcrypt gem is just used to hash the password_digest attribute.

The has_secure_password method is actually very short ([source here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods/has_secure_password)), and contains one line that requires the password to be confirmed:

```
# File activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb, line 34
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of     :password_digest
```

So, overriding the has_secure_password method by creating a modified version in your config/initializers folder should work. Commenting out the "validates_confirmation_of" line will turn off password confirmation. You could also rewrite the method, of course, to take an options hash like you tried to do in your question.

Comment: please what are steps to override has_secure_password method ?